# Display group_concat results in php

Tags: php, mysql

I use a group concat in my query that returns a single result row (Thats wy i use group concat). But how To display the results of the group concat, is there a way with an array pointer maybe? There are always 9 results in the group concat vallue....

Comment: Please show the SQL code and the query results so we have a better idea what you're talking about.  Just edit your post, don't post it here in comments.

Comment: Why would you let MySQL concat the rows into one string and then split it in PHP? Just return a record set and let PHP fetch each row should be just as easy and more flexible.

Comment: There's plenty of reasons to use a group concat. I'm using this approach to display complex relational data on a very humble shared hosting site (the table is created offline and uploaded to the site) - I only have to call one premade table and the PHP code is vastly less complex. Group concat also makes displaying relational data without duplicate content much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use php [explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get the concatenated values into array

```
$value = $row['concat_col'];
$values = explode(",", $value); //assuming you group_concat used commas e.g. John,James,Jim

//$values is an array of strings concatenated by group_concat
echo $values[0]; //John
echo $values[1]; //Jim
```